# Using TextStream Method WriteBlankLines

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub tryMethod()

    Dim objTxt as textstream

    Dim filename as string
        fileName = "Z:\New folder\TextDoc.txt"

    Set fSo = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set objTxt = fSo.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForReading)

    str = objTxt.WriteBlankLines(1)

End Sub
```

No matter what number I put into the brackets after calling method writeblanklines I get the following error:

> expected function or variable

I have checked documentation and do not see an example for this method. First two pages of google also didn't give me an example to work off of.

Comment: `objTxt.WriteBlankLines(1)` maybe? Are you sure that method returns something? http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/vbscript/textstream-writeblanklines.html

Comment: removed the set equals to and right side of the equation, now getting a bad file mode error. edit nvm I set to read only then tried to write into file LOL

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/opentextfile-method

Comment: to be fair, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/writeblanklines-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have opened the file for reading `Set objTxt = fSo.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForReading)` and you are trying to write.
This is how to open it for writing:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim objTxt As TextStream
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\nd.txt"

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set objTxt = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForWriting)
    objTxt.WriteBlankLines 23

End Sub
```

---

[The MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/opentextfile-method) (from @braX comment) is not as good as one would expect - the `ForWriting` constant is present only in the example:

[image]

However, the `ForWriting` [is present in the GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/blob/master/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/opentextfile-method.md), maybe one day when the MSDN and the GitHub would be sync-ed it will be there as well:

[image]